# Why this error `Run-time :Application-defined or object-defined error` although using If (InCellDropdown = True)

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code to automatically open Dropdown List. 
In my test range I intentionally left some cells without any data validation, 
I thought the event will not be firing (on cells without data validation) after I used this line 
`If Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = True Then`
But I got that error

> Run-time error '1004':Application-defined or object-defined error

**Is this if condition useless ?** thanks for any learning assistance

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing And _
      Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 And Target.Row > 1 Then
 
      If Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = True Then
        Application.SendKeys ("%{DOWN}")
      End If
 
End If
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly useless, it's just a thing VBA does: if the target has no validation, it brings up your error, because cells, that have validation are treated as `SpecialCells`, not as regular Cells, if that makes sense. Anyway, to make your code work, you can try:

```
On Error Resume Next
  If Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = True Then
    Application.SendKeys ("%{DOWN}")
  End If
On Error GoTo 0
```